# Impossible RuntimeException: Stub with Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

I'm using Maven to build and test a project in IntelliJ IDEA with Robolectric. I have Robolectric declared before Android in the POM, and I've used the SDK deployer to install to my local repo. But I still keep getting this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
>       at android.net.Uri.$$robo$$Uri_30fc_parse(Uri.java:53)
>       at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$InvocationPlan.callOriginal(ShadowWrangler.java:591)
>       at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java)
>       at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMediaStore.reset(ShadowMediaStore.java:27)
>       at org.robolectric.Robolectric.resetStaticState(Robolectric.java:821)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.resetStaticState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:224)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:133)
>       at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:96)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)

And my pom.xml is exactly as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.jemson</groupId>
<artifactId>notecloud-mobile</artifactId>
<version>.01</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>Note-Cloud Mobile</name>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>offline</id>
        <properties>
            <config.scheme>http://</config.scheme>
            <config.host>10.0.2.2</config.host>
            <config.path>/notecloudtest/index.html</config.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>online</id>
        <properties>
            <config.scheme></config.scheme>
            <config.host></config.host>
            <config.path></config.path>
        </properties>

    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.logician</groupId>
        <artifactId>abstractmodel</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.androidquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-query</artifactId>
        <version>0.24.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>12</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>templates/Config.java</file>
                    <outputFile>src/main/java/org/jemson/notecloud/Config.java</outputFile>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>#scheme</token>
                            <value>${config.scheme}</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>#host</token>
                            <value>${config.host}</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>#path</token>
                            <value>${config.path}</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- See http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ -->
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
</build>
```

AbstractModel is my own personal convenience library. It does not use the Uri class anywhere internally. As for Android-Query, I'm not sure. What I think is the problematic call to Uri.parse() is in the Activity class I'm testing; I've tried commenting the call out to see what would happen but the exception is still thrown.

I've tried moving the Robolectric dependencies around in the IntelliJ module configuration to make sure they are in fact being included before Android. I've matched my POM and .iml files as closely to the RobolectricSample project files as possible. I've even deleted all the IntelliJ files in the project tree and re-opened the project from the POM. Nothing.

I am absolutely flummoxed. I've tried everything I can think of. I'm considering scrapping Robolectric for this project and just running the app in the emulator to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm have the same problem as you. And also one [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753281/robolectric-sqlitestatement-executeupdatedelete-doesnt-perform-any-action).

> useless text cut

**Update 1.**

Found this issue on github:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/426

Some peoples talk that on mac os it works..

**Update 2.**

Found workaround (comment by [esam091](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/issues/426#issuecomment-15677826)):

```
public class YourTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner
{
    public YourTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError
    {
        super(RobolectricContext.bootstrap(YourTestRunner.class, testClass,
            new RobolectricContext.Factory()
            {
                @Override
                public RobolectricContext create()
                {
                    return new RobolectricContext()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean useAsm() // this override does the trick
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected AndroidManifest createAppManifest()
                        {
                            return new AndroidManifest(
                                new File("YourApp/src/main/android/AndroidManifest.xml"),
                                new File("YourApp/src/main/android/resources"));
                        }
                    };
                }
            }));
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareTest(Object test)
    {
        RoboGuice.injectMembers(Robolectric.application, test);
    }
}
```

Specify `@RunWith(YourTestRunner.class)` on each test which uses Android API.

**Update 3.**

Issue fixed:
https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/pull/458

Comment: Yeah, I had this figured out not long after I posted the question. I was thinking about implementing it but I decided that the time spent implementing wouldn't be balanced by the time saved using unit tests instead of testing manually with an emulator. Maybe after I finish this project.