# Exception when using Robolectric + ActionBarSherlock

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, robolectric

I have big problem with using Robolectric with ActionBarSherlock.

I don't why but it seems that Roboletric cannot find one class:

Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.support.v4.app.Watson.$$robo$$Watson_7e47___constructor__()
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1937)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler$InvocationPlan.callOriginal(ShadowWrangler.java:589)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.methodInvoked(ShadowWrangler.java:185)
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricInternals.methodInvoked(RobolectricInternals.java:118)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.__constructor__(Watson.java)
    at android.content.Context.<init>(Context.java)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.<init>(ContextWrapper.java)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.<init>(ContextThemeWrapper.java)
    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.Watson.<init>(Watson.java)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.<init>(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:21)
    at pl.activities.CoreFragmentMenuActivity.<init>(CoreFragmentMenuActivity.java:21)
    at pl.activities.CoreNavigationActivity.<init>(CoreNavigationActivity.java:16)
    at pl.activities.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:18)
    at MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:20)
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(CustomTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest
{
    private MainActivity activity;
    private Button pressMeButton;
    private TextView results;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        activity = new MainActivity();
        activity.onCreate(null);

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldUpdateResultsWhenButtonIsClicked() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(activity.getTitle(), activity.getResources().getString(R.string.activity_main_title));
    }
}
```

CustomTestRunner:

```
import java.io.File;

public class CustomTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner
{
    public CustomTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError
    {
        super(RobolectricContext.bootstrap(CustomTestRunner.class, testClass,
                new RobolectricContext.Factory()
                {
                    @Override
                    public RobolectricContext create()
                    {
                        return new RobolectricContext()
                        {
                            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603583/impossible-runtimeexception-stub-with-robolectric
                            @Override
                            public boolean useAsm() // this override does the trick
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected AndroidManifest createAppManifest()
                            {
                                return new AndroidManifest(
                                        new File("AndroidManifest.xml"),
                                        new File("res"));
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }));
    }
```

I am using:

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
         <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
         <version>2.0-alpha-2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Interesting, which versions of ABS and support are you using? Could you also post result of "mvn dependency:tree"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've run into it yet, but Robolectric has released a blog post about compatibility with ABS. [Check it out](http://robolectric.blogspot.com/2013/03/using-actionbarsherlock-with.html). Hopefully it solves your issue.